# Meaning of the verb "number" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It was in [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/TG55ErfdaeY). It is at 1 minute and 53 second. Here it goes:

> Your descendants will **number** the stars, and you can have the land of Canaan forever.

I have checked all the meanings of the verb, but still I cannot get it. I guess the speaker meant by that that the descendants will amount to the number of stars, but I am not sure because in all the examples given by the online dictionaries, there must be some number after the verb *number*. For example:

> After the hurricane the homeless numbered over 200,000.

Is it possible that the presenter meant *outnumber the stars*?

Comment: It’s figurative language, so it doesn’t really matter if _number_ means “outnumber” or “number the same as.” The point is: “Your descendants will be as countless as the stars.”

Comment: It's at the very least an "unusual" usage. Having recently been reading up on [Gaia Data Release 2](https://www.gaia.ac.uk/data/gaia-data-release-2) I was initially tempted to interpret ***number*** as *[be able to] **enumerate / count up** [the stars]*. But they didn't have astronomers with telescopes in Abraham's day, only astrologers.with fervent imaginations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When **number** is used as a verb that means "be as numerous as, have a count equalling", the complement can be either a number such as 50,000, a quantifying pronoun like **few** or **many** or **thousands**, or a multitude. It is not used that last way in conversation nowadays. It is [an older (oratorical) use](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22can%20not%20number%20the%20dead%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), and the multitude is something vast and virtually uncountable.